# Flutter dependency issue with Kotlin and Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, flutter

I'm having an issue building an app for Android that runs fine on iOS. The error reads:

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method classpath() for arguments
>   [org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Here are my dependencies in the build.gradle in the app module:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To include a var inside a string, you need double quotes:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Just as you can see here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Answer (score -1):

The `classpath` configuration is a special one defined at the `buildscript` level which allows to tweak the classpath of the *build script*.

So in order to add the `gradle-kotlin-plugin`, you need to do the following:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version'
    }
}
```

See the [relevant documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1/userguide/plugins.html#sec:applying_plugins_buildscript) for more details.